# running two LEDs with two buttons

Tags: arduino, led

I am new to Arduino programing. I am trying to get two buttons to light two LEDs like so. press button1 turn on light 1 turn off light 2, button2 turn on light 1 and 2. like indicators for speed selection.

this is the code I have so far.

```
const int BUTTON1 = 2;
const int BUTTON2 = 3;
const int LED1 = 9;
const int LED2 = 10;
int BUTTONstate1 = 0;
int BUTTONstate2 = 0;


void setup()
{
pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT);
pinMode(BUTTON2, INPUT);
pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(1)
{
BUTTONstate1 = digitalRead(BUTTON1);
if (BUTTONstate1 == HIGH);

digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
digitalwrite(LED2, low);
} 

void loop(2)
{
BUTTONstate2 = digitalRead(BUTTON2);
if (BUTTONstate2 == HIGH)

digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
digitalwrite(led2, HIGH);
}
```

when i run the code I get ERROR 19:10 error: variable or field 'loop' declared void.  it is the line after void loop(1) and void loop(2).

Comment: Please tag your question properly!

Comment: im new to this what do you mean and how

Comment: You've added tag "python", it leads to confusion. Please remove it and add tags "arduino", "led" for example. Click "edit" button.

Comment: i think i fixed it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If it is fixed, you can provide an answer on how it was fixed. Understand that this is not a bank of solutions, but ... Continuous study and exchange of accurate information. Vague statements make it difficult to reproduce ... And this solution must already be in our database ... Google is also a solution.
This is now believed to be a programming error. Please report the detailed error.

Answer (score 1):

`void loop(1)` and `void loop(2)` don't make sense.

You only implement `void loop()` and handle both buttons in that function.

Arduino will call `loop()` in an infinite loop over and over. Having two loop functions doesn't make sense and causes compiler errors.

If you want to have that functionality in two different functiosn implement them using different names and call both of them inside `loop()`

Comment: I knew I was making it more complicated than I needed to. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen someone uses two void loops at one time. You have to use only one `void loop()`. Here is an example:

```
void loop() {
    BUTTONstate1 = digitalRead(BUTTON1);
    BUTTONstate2 = digitalRead(BUTTON2);
    if (BUTTONstate1 == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
        digitalwrite(LED2, LOW);
    }
    if (BUTTONstate2 == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
        digitalwrite(LED2, HIGH);
    }
}
```

You also make another error here. Don't ever print `;` after `if()`

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick and explained a lot. can this concept be expanded to three or four led/buttons

Comment: Yes, you can expand more. But use **switch case** instead of **if else** to make your code more understandable.